# Is it possible to invoke a call in Google Duo via intent? This code seems close

Tags: java, android, android-intent, deep-linking, phone-call

In the stock Contacts, Messaging, and Phone apps, there is a button that allows users to use audio and video calling via Google Duo. I would like this functionality in my app.

Currently, I am only able to reach the main page of Google Duo, each **Intent** is showing some error in the Logcat that I believe is preventing me from reaching the calling function through.

I've run some tests and created an Intent with 
    Package =

  "com.google.android.apps.tachyon"

, the package for Google Duo.

I then created a **PackageManager** and iterated over the **ResolveInfo** found from the 
    pm.queryIntentActivities()
 function. This returned some interesting results being that I could request the following, explicitly named packages.

```
Packages Found :
com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsAudioActionActivity
com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsAudioActionActivity2
com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsVideoActionActivity
com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsVideoActionActivity2
```

I've Also done some logcat searching and found these two '''Intent types''' being checked.

```
Types Found:
vnd.android.cursor.item/com.google.android.apps.tachyon.phone.audio
vnd.android.cursor.item/com.google.android.apps.tachyon.phone
```

Upon further testing, I've found that the latter **.phone type** is for the Video packages and the **.phone.audio type** is for the Audio packages... So I ran even more tests...

```
Results:
Packages: .ContactsAudioActionActivity2 and 
.ContactsVideoActionActivity2 require a permission, CALL_PRIVILEDGED 
that is only given to system apps. This is not a system app. These are 
the packages the stock Contacts, Phone, and Messaging apps use

Packages: .ContactsAudioActionActivity and .ContactsVideoActionActivity 
leaves me at the main screen of Google Duo no matter the data I pass. 
More on that in a bit.
```

I ended up with this Intent format, with the presumed issue being the Data I am setting.

```
private void openGoogleDuo(){
    // Leaves Log Error "executeCallFromContactsApps: result doesn't contain a number"  (I checked the _ids and everything)
    Uri data1 = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/1234");

    // Leaves Log Error "External start call intent missing data (e.g. "content://com.android.contacts/data/123").
    Uri data0 = Uri.parse("content://phone/5135554235");
    Uri data2 = Uri.parse("tel: +15135553245");
    Uri data3 = Uri.parse("tel: 5133455513");

    // ALL DATA OPENS THE APP, BUT NO CALL...

    String audioCallType = "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.google.android.apps.tachyon.phone.audio";
    String videoCallType = "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.google.android.apps.tachyon.phone";

    String mainGoogleDuoPackage = "com.google.android.apps.tachyon";

    String videoCallPackage = "com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsVideoActionActivity"; // CALL_PRIVILEGE locked package appends '2'
    String audioCallPackage = "com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsAudioActionActivity"; // CALL_PRIVILEGE locked package appends '2'

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(data1 , audioCallType);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(mainGoogleDuoPackage, audioCallPackage));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setPackage(audioCallPackage);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Expected results are to instantly invoke the audio or video call to the specified contact/phone number in Google Duo without any further user input.

This code is leaving me at the main screen of Google Duo.

Any help would be honorable.

Comment: ever figure this out? it appears Google does not want us instrumenting Duo. :(